# Filling a vector of bytes with random bytes

Tags: c++

I wanted to fill a `std::vector<BYTE>` with random or pseudo-random bytes of data. I have written (in other word, find it) the following source code in the stackoverflow but it doesn't compile in my Visual Studio.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, BYTE>;

int main()
{
    random_bytes_engine rbe;
    std::vector<BYTE> data(1000);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ref(rbe));
}
```

When I try to compile the above code Visual studio give me the following errors:

> Error C2338   note: char, signed char, unsigned char, char8_t, int8_t,
> and uint8_t are not allowed   Messaging
>
> Error C2338   invalid template argument for independent_bits_engine:
> N4659 29.6.1.1 [rand.req.genl]/1f requires one of unsigned short,
> unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long    Messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Evg is correct.

If you really want to have random bytes only, I would use a custom generator function that generates values between [-128, 127] or any desired range.
For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine randomEngine(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniformDist(CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);

    std::vector<BYTE> data(1000);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [&uniformDist, &randomEngine] () {
        return (BYTE) uniformDist(randomEngine);

    });

    for (auto i : data) {
        std::cout << int(i) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

References:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<BYTE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<BYTE>::max()` would be clearer.

Comment: I did use them initially, but it somehow did not compile with msvc 19.20 (on godbolt.org). That's why I reverted my answer to CHAR_MIN / CHAR_MAX.

Comment: @Anton That's a known problem in MSVC. Just define the `NOMINMAX` macro before including `Windows.h`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ehjxTr) - If you use the `C` macros, use `(0, UCHAR_MAX)` instead of `(CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX)` and the distribution should preferably be using an `unsigned` type.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I've not programmed in C++ on Windows for like 11 years ago.

Comment: Lately I've been initializing the random generators and distributions in the generator lambda capture list, to keep my scopes clean (it's not required anywhere else). Need C++17 for this though. E.g. `[uniformDist = std::uniform_int_distribution(std::numeric_limits<BYTE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<BYTE>::max()), randomEngine = std::default_random_engine{std::random_device{}()}] () mutable { return uniformDist(randomEngine); }`

Comment: also, according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) the default template argment of `std::uniform_int_distribution` is `int`. However, it seems MSVC has some issues with argument type deduction, which gcc and clang don't have.

Answer (score 2):

The `BYTE` type, which is just an alias for `unsigned char`, is not an allowed type for `UIntType` parameter of

```
template<class Engine, std::size_t W, class UIntType>
class independent_bits_engine;
```

The standard, [rand.req.genl]/1.f, [reads](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/rand.req.genl#1.f):

> Throughout this subclause [rand], the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> ...
>
> - that has a template type parameter named `UIntType` is undefined unless the corresponding  template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this instead:

```
using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, 32, uint32_t>;
```

Turns the engine into a 32-bit random number generator, but using it to initialize a vector of BYTEs works just fine.